# Python convert list of tuples to dictionary with value of multiple tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't what to do with this because I can't append tuples and I just showed it with list as default

```
Dict = dict()
def convert(list_tup):
    for a,b,c in list_tup:
        letters = a,b 
        number = c
        Dict.setdefault(number,[]).append(letters)  
        # I only want a multiple tuple values not list of tuple
    return Dict
strings = [('w', 'x','2'), ('y', 'z', '3')]
print(convert(strings))
```

it prints `{'2': [('w', 'x')], '3': [('y', 'z')]}`

how can I add multiple tuples as value in one key?

I want my output to be like this:

```
{'2': ('w', 'x'), '3': ('y', 'z')}
```

Comment: You can append multiple `tuple` in list right.

Comment: You can save time by using following statement - `dict(list(map(lambda x: (x[2], (x[0], x[1])), strings)))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following dict comprehension should solve this

```
>>> {c: (a,b) for a,b,c in strings}
{'2': ('w', 'x'), '3': ('y', 'z')}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just make new entries in the output dictionary by keying `c` for the value `(a,b)`:

```
def convert(list_tup):
    d = {}
    for a,b,c in list_tup:
        d[c] = (a,b)
    return d
```

But Cory's answer is more